# Set part of a picture as button

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have one larger image and would like to make only one smaller part of that image (that part is in the center of the image) to serve as button, i.e. to be clickable. Is that possible?

Comment: `Is that possible?` - Yes. **What have you Tried???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add some transparent element, e.g. rectangle. Then handle **Tap** event. Here's my example:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Image.jpg"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Rectangle Width="48" 
               Height="48" 
               Fill="Transparent" 
               Tap="Rectangle_Tap" />
</Grid>
```

And this is how it looks in Visual Studio:
[image]

The little rectangle is invisible but user can tap it.
Note that in Windows Phone if control is transparent or has opacity set to 0, it still reacts to user input.